# Java Enviroment class problem with getting properties

Tags: java, spring, database, datasource

I created new Enviroment in SpringConfig file:

```
private final Environment environment;
@Autowired
public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext, Environment environment) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    this.environment = environment;
}
```

And file database.properties

```
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/first_db
username=root
password=1234
```

Created dataSource bean

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("driver")));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("password"));

        return dataSource;
    }
```

It gave me error and I checked what enviroment.getProperty returns me. It showed me:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/first_db
PC // my PC name
1234
```

So why does enviroment returns me my Pc's name? How do I know what properties are already assigned?

Comment: The environment variable `%USERNAME%` that comes from Windows has a higher priority than that defined by your file. Try prefixing all variables inside that file with, for example, `database.` and then call `getProperty("database.username")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75120892/java-enviroment-class-problem-with-getting-properties/75122156#comment132564287_75120892) from [Alex R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7970787/alex-r) about the `%USERNAME%` variable having a higher priority. Using a prefix for values in your `.properties` files is a good practice and will help you avoid a lot of conflicts like this.

Alternatively, you can use the `ResourceBundle` class.

With `database.properties` at the top level of your Java resources (if not at the top level, just provide the path to the `database.properties` file), the snippet below will give you what you need:

```
final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("database");
final String username = bundle.getString("username");
final String password = bundle.getString("password");
```

Comment: Thank you! I hope it will help some people with database connectivity problems.